# RecylerView not animating insert, however it does animate removal

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

So when I add an item it does not animate it in, nor does it scroll to the correct position. However it will animate the object removal when I delete something.

Here is the add code:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == NEWITEMREQUESTCODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // AFTER CREATING A NEW ITEM
            OilChangeableItem oilChangeableItem = data.getParcelableExtra("oil_item");
            // Add the new item and notify the dataset.
            oilChangeableAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
            items.add(0, oilChangeableItem);
        } else if (requestCode == EDITITEMRESULTCODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // AFTER EDITING AN ITEM
            OilChangeableItem oilChangeableItem = data.getParcelableExtra("oil_item");
            // Replace the existing item at whatever position it was originally at and notify the dataset.
            oilChangeableAdapter.notifyItemChanged(data.getIntExtra("item_position", 0));
            items.set(data.getIntExtra("item_position", 0), oilChangeableItem);
        }
    }
```

And here is the removal code:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_delete_title);
                    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_warning);
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_delete_message);

                    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_text_delete, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // Removed the selected item
                            oilChangeableAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(oilChangeableAdapter.getSelectedViewPosition());
                            items.remove(oilChangeableAdapter.getSelectedViewPosition());
                            // Notify the user it has been removed.
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.toast_item_deleted, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.button_text_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    });
                builder.create();
                builder.show();
                mode.finish();
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why do you call `notifyItemInserted` before actually insert the item?

Comment: @rciovati I've tried it afterwards and it still doesn't work :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because you are adding the item "above" the currently visible items.

I understand this looks unexpected if you think about the first position but if RV was showing items from 5 to 10 and a new item is added at position 2, you really don't want your list to move to 4 to 9.

So LinearLayoutManager keeps this simple, if an item is added above or below the list, it does not move around (so that UX is consistent).

If you want it to show position 0 when you add an item to position 0, call
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0) after adding the item. I think what you really want is:

```
items.add(0, oilChangeableItem);    
oilChangeableAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
if (layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0) {
    layoutManager.scrollToPosition(0);
}
```

Comment: So it will scroll to the item, but it still won't animated the item fading in like it does when you remove an item.

Comment: Hmm it should if you are calling scroll to position. What are you seeing? İt just jumps and don't animate any view?

Comment: Yeah it'll just jump to it. Or if I'm just adding an item for the first time, it'll just pop up and won't fade in.

Comment: That's weird. You have not set item animator to null right? Default item animator does not work on gingerbread and animations are disabled in battery saving mode. If you can upload a sample project, I'm  happy to look at it

Comment: :/, it is happening because the code in question runs in onActivityResult. RV does not run animations in the first layout pass after being attached because it looks weird to fade in everything :/. As a workaround, you can postpone adding the item to the next frame using a handler. 10 ms would do it. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to find that issue! Just out of curiosity how'd you know RV didn't run on the first pass and that onActivityResult did?

Comment: Because i worked on it :) which is why i take any issue serious. Glad it is resolved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65473/discussion-between-doubleelite-and-yigit).

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar to what you want to do. If you are adding the item in onActivityResult, then we must have a look at when onActivityResult actually gets called in the activity lifecycle. The method is called before onResume() when your activity is re-starting. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent) This means that even before the activity comes on screen your item is already added and hence you cannot see it. You will have to use the 10ms delay as yigit suggested.

Comment: I would scroll in all the cases, not only if your first visible is 0. What if you are in the last and add one? with this you wouldnt scroll